# Rails 4.0 btn-btn-danger button issues

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, heroku

When i add the twitter bootstrap 3.0  danger button to my code and run it in heroku it looks shaded out. However when i run the app in  localhost it looks normal. The code i am using is as follows

```
<%= link_to "Post a job Today: $169 for 45 days", new_listing_path , class: "btn btn-danger btn-lg" %>
```

button in heroku/production mode:

[image: button in heroku/production mode]

button displayed in localhost:

[image: button displayed in localhost]

bootstrap.css file

```
@import 'bootstrap';


.btn-lg {
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

also remove the default scaffold.css file

updated 17/06

inspect element on Chrome shows #FFF (white) - Correct
on firefox it shows #666 (dark)

so how would i change this as not come across this before

Comment: When you open up your console, do you get any "404 file not found" errors indicating it couldn't find certain CSS files?  Is it possible you're expecting a manifest CSS file to be available on heroku but aren't setting it to be precompiled in your `production.rb`?  What differences do you see when you inspect the element with your browser's web inspector?  What causes the text color to be different (which specific CSS file/rules).

Comment: update it works in chrome but not in firefox

Comment: Sounds like a browser issue if it works in Chrome but not FireFox. Agree with nzifnab that you should try inspecting in the browser to see where the CSS text color is coming from.

Comment: inspect element on Chrome shows #FFF (white) - Correct
on firefox it shows #666 (dark)

Answer (score 0):

deleted the line <%= link_to "Post a job Today: $169 for 45 days", new_listing_path , class: "btn btn-danger btn-lg" %> updated the file . Adde back the line and now works